# advanced ajax page loader (wordpress) make jquery slide toggle not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi i am trying to make a slide animation for a custom filed in wordpress
I use Advanced Ajax Page loader the first page have the slide toggle but even i go to second page it is going to stop working and even i comeback to main page It 's not working too.

The loop code :

```
<div class="long-box">

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<img class="longim" id="c-<?php the_ID(); ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=150&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1" alt="" />
<?php } else { ?>
<img class="longim" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dummy.png&amp;h=150&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1"  alt="" />
<?php } ?>
<p id="m-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="display: none;"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'need',true); ?></p>
<script>
$( "#c-<?php the_ID(); ?>" ).hover(function() {
$( "#m-<?php the_ID(); ?>" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your PHP, if your requested `<img>` does not have a thumbnail, it loses the `id` attribute that you have on the thumbnail-holding `<img>`.

On line 8, change this:

```
<img class="longim" src="<?php ...
```

to this:

```
<img class="longim" id="c-<?php the_ID(); ?>" src="<?php ...
```

and let me know if it helps.

If this was working before you added the page loader and still doesn't work, check the JS console for errors.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working And is there another way to do this